# Issue while migrating to Richfaces 4

Tags: tomcat, richfaces

I have followed strictly all points mentioned in this document, but when i run my application, 
it reports following problem while running on Tomcat 6.0.29

(i have Mozzara 2.0.4 and jstl1.1 included in classpath).

Application works perfectly on Richfaces 3.3.3

**It is JSf 2 application**

> SEVERE: Context [/e360] startup failed due to previous errors
>   Jun 10, 2011 1:48:05 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextDestroyed
>   SEVERE: Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at org.richfaces.application.CacheProvider.release(CacheProvider.java:86)
>           at org.richfaces.application.ServicesFactoryImpl.release(ServicesFactoryImpl.java:19)
>           at org.richfaces.application.ServiceTracker.release(ServiceTracker.java:100)
>           at org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener.onStop(InitializationListener.java:144)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<filter>
    <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>createTempFiles</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>        
    <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
    <param-value>#{ThemeBean.theme}</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
    <param-value>enable</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

You no longer need filter configuration in RichFaces 4.

Comment: But even after that, it says same thing : Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime